# VBA Excel handling ranges with for each

Tags: excel, vba

Quick question:

I set three ranges `sourceRng1` and `sourceRng2` `targetRng`. All equal of size.

I want to achieve this:

```
For each cell in targetRng
    cell.value = sourceRng1 / sourceRng2
next cell
```

where the index of `sourceRng1` and `sourceRng2` jumps one step in each iteration.

So if the first and second values of `sourceRng1` and `sourceRng2` are `4 7` and `1 3`

then `cell.value = 4/1` in the first iteration. `cell.value = 7/3` in the second.

Any suggestion on how to do this operation?

Comment: seems that you know how to do it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim x as long
For x=1 to targetRng.cells.count
    targetRng.Cells(x).value = sourceRng1.cells(x).value / sourceRng2.Cells(x).value
next cell
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a non-VBA solution as well:

1. select `targetRng`
2. type formula `=sourceRng1 / sourceRng2`
3. press **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter** to enter this as an [Array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx)

[image]

Downside being you cannot edit - e.g. delete - parts of Array formulas separately, only when you select the whole area => make sure to use a different background color or comments to distinguish `targetRng` from other cells.